# Spring Reactive events and transactional Context

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I am migrating one existing app from Spring MVC traditional model to Spring Reactive. My first refactor let me with this piece of code:

```
return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> visitRequestDao.findById(requestId).get())
            .map(request ->  request.approve())
            .map(request -> ResponseEntity.ok(listOfPendingVisitRequest(owner)));
```

After execute the endpoint I noticed that my entity did not have the state changed. As a Hibernate user, I know that when I load some object, any change applied will be reflect in the database, after the commit. My guess was that the event was executing in a different thread. I changed the code a little bit.

```
return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> visitRequestDao.findById(requestId).get())
            .map(request -> transactionalContext.execute(() -> request.approve()))
            .map(request -> ResponseEntity.ok(listOfPendingVisitRequest(owner)))
```

A class `TransactionalContext` was created and marked as transactional. So, now I know that any time its method is called, a new transactional will be started or a current one will be used. Is this the correct approach? Is there any solution?

Comment: _" Is there any solution?"_ Solution for what? What happens inside `request.approve()` is relevant for both the question and the answer.

Comment: request.approve() changes the internal state of the object.